# How can I create a new table in a database in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, database

I have an MVC 5 app, which uses MySQL hosted in Azure as a data source. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider), and at the moment I have these [tables](http://i3.asp.net/media/4618186/image015.jpg?cdn_id=2014-07-01-001). The point is that inside the database, I want to create a new table called "request". I have already activated migrations for my database in code. I also have the following code in my app.

**Request.cs:** (inside Models folder)

```
public class Request
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Request type")]
    public string RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

**Test.cshtml:**

```
@model Workfly.Models.Request
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAndShare", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new request.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RequestType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RequestType, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "keywords-manual" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit!" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAndShare(Request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var req = new Request { RequestType = request.RequestType };
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Share");
    }
```

The point is that, I want the user to fill the form inside the Test view and click submit, and when the submit is clicked, I want a new entry in the new table to be created. But first of course I need to create the table. Should I create it using SQL query through MySQL workbench? If yes, then how can I connect the new table with my code? I guess I need some DB context but don't know how to do it. If someone can post some code example, I would be glad.

**UPDATE:**

I created a new class inside the Models folder and named it RequestContext.cs, and its contents can be found below:

```
public class RequestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I did `"Add-Migration Request"`, and `"Update-Database"` commands, but still nothing. Please also note that I have a MySqlInitializer class, which looks something like this:

```
public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            // if database did not exist before - create it
            context.Database.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database 
            var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
            string.Format(
              "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
              ""));

            // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
            if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try "update-database" command on Package Manager Console?

Comment: @Gandarez Yes, it doesn't work, check my update.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a DbContext class and add your DbSet referencing your Request class.  Then use the console to add-migration and update-database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Delete the migrations you have currently, add the db context class and the dbset to reference the request class and then add your migrations again. Had a similar problem when trying to deploy on azure and this worked.